# Qt Installer Framework: How to sign the maintenancetool.exe

Tags: c++, qt, installation, code-signing

I have build an installer for my application with the QtIFW2.0.1 on Windows. As we offer the installer for download, I have signed the installer executable with a valid certificate. So our verified name shows up while the installation process ask for the needed access rights.
Nevertheless there is an [unpleasant messagebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QznRc.png) if the user uninstalls, updates or changes our application via the maintenancetool.exe. 
How is it possible to extract the maintenancetool.exe, sign it and put it back in the installer executable?

Comment: Can't you alow only admins to use the maintancetool.exe in order to avoid this error message box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintenancetool signing in Windows ([QTIFW-667](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-667)) is possible since Qt Installer Framework version 3.1.0 which was released April 11th 2019.